# What causes jetty badMessage: 413 for HttpChannelOverHttp

Tags: java, http, header, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have an application with an embedded jetty server, I have noticed for some web/browser GET requests application throws this message
`badMessage: 413 for HttpChannelOverHttp` from *org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser* and ultimately 413 responses. I am not sure what is causing this error and how to solve this.

Based on documentation it could be related to the request header size, but header size is almost the same (but not sure about the cookie part), Even if it is related to header size how can I configure the server to accept the request with a bigger payload.

Java version= *openjdk version "1.8.0_181"*
Jetty Version= *9.2.26.v20180806*

P.S.: I'm new to web development with java
Thanks

Comment: Your request URL and/or headers are too large. Try making them smaller or modifying your servers settings to up the max size

Comment: Please provide some information like exact error message, failure stack trace etc.

Comment: I needed to configure the server with setRequestHeaderSize() as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792358/programmatically-set-jetty-configuration-to-increase-allowed-url-length